# Auto-Hiding Navigation - Disable Primary-Nav when scrolled up but showed only at the very top

Tags: jquery, html, css, navbar

sorry for my long question title up there . 
btw, i used this [template](https://codyhouse.co/gem/auto-hiding-navigation/) from codyhouse . which is the most awesome temp that i used. But now , i want my primary-nav not showed-up when scrolled up . only visible at the very top. please if anyone right there . please help me out . thank you so much .

btw, Here's the script

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var mainHeader = $('.cd-auto-hide-header'),
        secondaryNavigation = $('.cd-secondary-nav'),
        //this applies only if secondary nav is below intro section
        belowNavHeroContent = $('.sub-nav-hero'),
        headerHeight = mainHeader.height();

    //set scrolling variables
    var scrolling = false,
        previousTop = 0,
        currentTop = 0,
        scrollDelta = 10,
        scrollOffset = 150;


    $(window).on('scroll', function(){
        if( !scrolling ) {
            scrolling = true;
            (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
                ? setTimeout(autoHideHeader, 250)
                : requestAnimationFrame(autoHideHeader);
        }
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        headerHeight = mainHeader.height();
    });

    function autoHideHeader() {
        var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        ( belowNavHeroContent.length > 0 ) 
            ? checkStickyNavigation(currentTop) // secondary navigation below intro
            : checkSimpleNavigation(currentTop);

        previousTop = currentTop;
        scrolling = false;
    }

    function checkSimpleNavigation(currentTop) {
        //there's no secondary nav or secondary nav is below primary nav
        if (previousTop - currentTop > scrollDelta) {
            //if scrolling up...
            mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
        } else if( currentTop - previousTop > scrollDelta && currentTop > scrollOffset) {
            //if scrolling down...
            mainHeader.addClass('is-hidden');
        }
    }

    function checkStickyNavigation(currentTop) {
        //secondary nav below intro section - sticky secondary nav
        var secondaryNavOffsetTop = belowNavHeroContent.offset().top - secondaryNavigation.height() - mainHeader.height();

        if (previousTop >= currentTop ) {
            //if scrolling up... 
            if( currentTop < secondaryNavOffsetTop ) {
                //secondary nav is not fixed
                mainHeader.addClass('is-hidden');
                secondaryNavigation.removeClass('fixed slide-up');
                belowNavHeroContent.removeClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
            } else if( previousTop - currentTop > scrollDelta ) {
                //secondary nav is fixed
                mainHeader.addClass('is-hidden');
                secondaryNavigation.removeClass('slide-up').addClass('fixed'); 
                belowNavHeroContent.addClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
            }

        } else {
            //if scrolling down...  
            if( currentTop > secondaryNavOffsetTop + scrollOffset ) {
                //hide primary nav
                mainHeader.addClass('is-hidden');
                secondaryNavigation.addClass('fixed slide-up');
                belowNavHeroContent.addClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
            } else if( currentTop > secondaryNavOffsetTop ) {
                //once the secondary nav is fixed, do not hide primary nav if you haven't scrolled more than scrollOffset 
                mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');
                secondaryNavigation.addClass('fixed').removeClass('slide-up');
                belowNavHeroContent.addClass('secondary-nav-fixed');
            }

        }
    }
});
```

I tried to change the  `mainHeader.removeClass('is-hidden');` to `mainHeader.addClass('is-hidden');` in function `checkSimpleNavigation(currentTop)` . it worked , the primary-nav is now not showing when scrolled up but also not showing up at the very top of the site . which is the problem here .

Here's a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ozJmGp) what i have so far

Comment: Have you tried doing it yourself? Show me some of you code first and explain how you approached your problem.

Comment: Sorry for that, i changed this section 
               //if scrolling up...
      mainHeader.addClass('is-hidden');
removeClass to addClass when scrolled-up . it worked but it's hidden even tough it's reached at the very top . so i want to remove the class "is-hidden" when reached at the very top .

Comment: Edit you question and paste your full code there as well as the explanation.

Comment: Done sir, with a pen. sorry , i'm a newbie of jquery here.

Comment: ok thanks this works but your question is a bit confusing. You want the top `nav` to stay always visible, is that it?

Comment: Like this https://getmdl.io/templates/portfolio/index.html from [MDL Templates](https://getmdl.io/templates/index.html)?

Comment: sorry to confused you . i only want is hide the primary-nav when scrolled down and scrolled up . cuz the template has the effect when you scrolled up the primary-nav is showed . but i only want is the primary-nav disabled or not showed when scrolled up . but show at the top of the site or primary-nav's position is as is. thanks